# Get specific columns and compare values php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to compare two values from two columns but it doesn't work correctly. Do I need to cast the results and what I am doing wrong?

```
$query = "SELECT `column1`, `column2` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ? ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$eventID);
$stmt->execute();
$currentJoin = (int)  $stmt->fetchColumn();
$maxParticipants = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn(1);

if ($currentJoin >= $maxParticipants) {
    return;
}
else {
```

Comment: You could also do this in the SQL. `SELECT CASE when columm1 >= columm2 then 1 else 0 end as is_great from ...` then fetch and use `is_great` index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Warning** There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use **PDOStatement::fetchColumn()** to retrieve data. - [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

You can use [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
if($result[0] >= $result[1] ){
    // ...
}
```